# In the film "The Quiet Earth" (1985), what happens to Zac Hobson in the final scene?

Tags: quiet-earth

At the end of this post-apocalyptic film, the central protagonist - Zac Hobson (Bruno Lawrence) - drives a truck laden with explosives onto the weakened roof of an underground laboratory. The explosives detonate ... and we witness a red flash. Hobson is now shown to be on a beach. In the distance can be seen strange clouds - and a large ringed planet rises over the horizon.

This ending is rather different from that of the original novel (by Craig Harrison), in which Hobson's character re-awakens at the start of the story - and is forced, it seems, to endlessly repeat his nightmare existence.

In the film, what has happened to Hobson? And where is he meant to be? In what way (if at all) is this connected to the 'Project Flashlight' described in the story?

Note - I'm after information about the final scene of the movie, and its meaning. I'm not asking a question about the film more generally (and am not seeking an explanation of the 'overall plot device' of the movie).

Comment: *"..different from that of the original novel.."* How did the novel end? (I always thought the end of the movie was intended to be vague, vaguely upbeat, and a cop-out.)

Comment: Hi - I've added a bit of info regarding the novel's ending. In the book, there's no giant alien planet or strange clouds.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quiet_Earth_%28film%29#Ambiguous_ending):

> **The precise meaning of the final scene is left to the audience.** In his commentary on the Umbrella Entertainment DVD release, writer/producer Sam Pillsbury states, "...we all thought it was quite simple; I mean, **our intention was just that, what happened was, he died at the moment of the effect for a second time and he's now found himself in another world**, what the hell's he gonna do...", he then says, more or less jokingly, that director Geoff Murphy being "a Catholic or lapsed Catholic, [it] may well have been something to do with purgatory, and y'know, you being trapped in cyclical and going back into having to relive your thing until you work out your karma, [something; possibly 'if I'm not'] mixing my metaphors; anyway, **enigmatic is good**, I think, to a certain extent..."

The ending is ambiguous, but it seems the intention was that just like Hobson survived his initial suicide because it occured at the exact moment of the effect, he intentionally triggered the explosion at the moment of the effect again to see what happened, and what happened was that he was transferred to another alternate world or dimension.

In the end, though, it's up to interpretation.